# Are there any ways to show code hints for javascript automatically in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I use Dreamweaver CS6 in Win7.
I know DW CS6 can show code hints for javascript by hitting ctrl + space in windows.
This time, I would like to know if there are any ways to show the code hints for javascript automatically by just typing some characters or marks without hitting the shortcut key or not.
I think it will reduce typing greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver code hint doesn't smart, sometimes will show code hint automatically when you make newline,
you have to use shortcut to open it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, is there any suggestions of editors which does code hints for Javascript smartly without hitting shortcut keys? If it's free, that'll be awesome.

Comment: try WebStorm — The smartest JavaScript IDE